# JQuery Listview maximum number of rows in filter

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a large dataset that contains usernames. I have attached this to a jquery listview which is set to filter-reveal.

I would like to be able to restrict the number of rows that the filter brings back.

I know how to override the filter to create a custom search, but i do not know how to restrict the number of item in the list (which would encourage the user to add more information to the filter)

Say i only wanted to show 2 results, if the users contained Tom, Tommy and Tony, and the filter was 'To' id expect to see only Tom and Tommy.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for `keyup` event and filter out the elements without class `ui-screen-hidden` which filter-reveal adds to the list items. Using `each` iteration over these filtered elements you can conditionally hide them using index value.

In the snippet below I'm checking if the index of each element is higher than 1 (second element) and hide them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
      $(".ui-input-text").keyup(() => {
        $("li").not(".ui-screen-hidden").each(function (i, obj) {
          i > 1 && $(this).hide();
        });
      })
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search numbers without hint..."
        data-inset="true" data-filter-reveal="true">
        <li data-filtertext="thirtyone">thirtyone
        </li>
        <li data-filtertext="thirtytwo">thirtytwo
        </li>
        <li data-filtertext="thirtythree">thirtythree
        </li>
        <li data-filtertext="thirtyfour">thirtyfour
        </li>
        <li data-filtertext="thirtyfive">thirtyfive
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why I am typing`thirtyf` and there are no results? Also noticed that this search works the first time when pasting.